# Select statement to turn table columns into rows

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL table called 'tblQuestions':

```
    questionID    Question      Option1 Option2 Option3 Option4 
      1          Whats 1 + 1         1     2       3      4
```

I am trying to do a select statement for the options, which will convert the row into the following format:

```
 AnswerText AnswerValue
    1          1    
    2          2
    3          3
    4          4
```

So to have each option instead as an individual column, but as separate rows instead

Apologies if table aren't in the correct format and thanks for the help!

Comment: Both AnswerText and AnswerValue columns have same value. How are they mapping to original table (row) ?

Comment: Seriously consider revising your schema. You could have a separate table for options.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag your questions only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 4):

I would strongly suggest restructuring your database to something like the following:

**tblQuestions**

`PK = Question_ID`

```
+-------------+--------------+
| Question_ID |   Question   |
+-------------+--------------+
|           1 | What is 1+1? |
|           2 | What is 2+2? |
|         ... | ...          |
+-------------+--------------+
```

**tblOptions**

`PK = Question_ID + Option_ID`

```
+-------------+-----------+--------------+
| Question_ID | Option_ID | Option_Value |
+-------------+-----------+--------------+
|           1 |         1 |            1 |
|           1 |         2 |            2 |
|           1 |         3 |            3 |
|           1 |         4 |            4 |
|           2 |         1 |            7 |
|           2 |         2 |            5 |
|           2 |         3 |            4 |
|         ... |       ... |          ... |
+-------------+-----------+--------------+
```

Then perhaps an answers table containing the correct options for each question -

**tblAnswers**

`PK = Question_ID`

```
+-------------+-----------+
| Question_ID | Option_ID |
+-------------+-----------+
|           1 |         2 |
|           2 |         3 |
|         ... |       ... |
+-------------+-----------+
```

Comment: I would have an AI PK on options(option_id), but your composite key idea works fine too.